# Cordova android PLUGMAN CREATEPACKAGEJSON . not working

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to create a plugin package.json file by 
[plugman createpackagejson .](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/#publishing-plugins) because I was on that plugin directory where plugin.xml located. Everytime it shows `pkg is not defined` .

Answer (score 1):

This is a know issue which was fixed with [this pull-request](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/597) which was already merged into master but not published yet, it will be available with the next release of cordova-lib.

For now you can create the `package.json` manually.